# Dynamically import typescript file that is provided during runtime (for changing server behavior)

Tags: typescript, dynamic

I'm running a Node server written in Typescript, trying to make a Google Firebase clone (just for fun, for my personal website).

I have a system for declarative creating rules for database access (similar to Firestore rules if you're familiar with that), with typing like this:

```js
interface Rule {
    read?: boolean | ((args: ReadValidationArguments) => boolean | undefined)
    write?: boolean | ((args: WriteValidationArguments) => Promise<boolean | undefined>)
    indexes?: Index[]
}

type Rules = Partial<Record<string, Rule>>

const rules: Rules = {
    "posts": {
        read: true,
        write: async ({session, fields}) => 
              args.session?.roles.includes("admin") 
              && fields.author?.uid === args.session?.uid
        indexes: [{field: "urlSlug", unique: true}]
    },
}
```

I then leverage those rules when determining authz for database reads/writes.

Right now, the rules are hardcoded in the backend, but I'd like to expose an endpoint on the server that takes a new rules.ts file, and dynamically compiles/loads it and uses it. I'd like it to be as typesafe as possible.

I've read a bit on using `import` dynamically, but I don't really have a good mental model for how the typing would play out. I was considering creating a subfolder in the server with it's own package.json and tsconfig, and dropping the file in there and doing an npm build on it.

Would that be a good pattern, and if so how should I implement it? Are there any other patterns or methods for doing this that I could use? How can I make it typesafe? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by having a subfolder called `/dynamic` with it's own package.json that has a `dynamicTypings.ts` file (and nothing else, initially).

The `dynamicTypings.ts` file defines the `Rules` type, and provides this function:

```js
export function testCompilation(rules: Rules) {
    return;
}
```

For my web server, I accept a rules.ts file from the client (with a proper API key, of course), and then I do 4 things:

- Write `rules.ts` to `/dynamic/rules.ts`
- Append the code `import rules from "./rules"; testCompilation(rules);` into the `dynamicTypings.ts` file
- Invoke `npm run build --prefix ./dynamic` to ensure type safety, and create the build/rules.js file
- Import the new `rules.js` module into my server code using a dynamic `await import` call

This is a bit of a implication, since I had to name the uploaded `rules.ts`
differently (with a timestamp as part of it's name) so that I could import it again, otherwise `import` uses a cache for the module and won't actually reload it. I'm going to try using a worker to load the module instead next, since that should bypass the module cache.

If there's another way, please feel free to provide an answer, but this is working pretty well for me and it gives me all the type safety I was looking for.